# Controlling ESC with Arduino

Tags: motor, pwm

I want to control these motors: [hexTronik DT750 Brushless Outrunner 750kv](http://www.hobbyking.com/hobbyking/store/uh_viewitem.asp?idproduct=6247&aff=61689) with this battery: [Turnigy 2200mAh 3S 25C Lipo Pack](http://www.hobbyking.com/hobbyking/store/uh_viewItem.asp?idProduct=8934&aff=61689) and these ESCs: [TURNIGY Plush 18amp Speed Controller](http://www.hobbyking.com/hobbyking/store/uh_viewItem.asp?idProduct=4312&Product_Name=TURNIGY_Plush_18amp_Speed_Controller&aff=61689).

I am new to this field of driving brush-less motors. Can someone tell me if I need anything else? Will this set-up work without anything getting destroyed?

Comment: This looks like shopping advice, which is off-topic for ee.se. See the [help] for advice. "Can someone tell me if I need anything else?" What do you actually want to do? The motor specification (spec) describes the max current 18A for a specific propeller, but only repeats the same value for its maximum current, which seems an odd coincidence. The ESC has a maximum continuous current of 18A, with a burst of 22A, but the specification doesn't say the burst duration. So it looks okay for some uses, but might not be for others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I 've been working on an autonomous arduino quadcopter for about 7 months now and I have a few tips for you.

1) your setup seems fine as long as your motors aren't going to draw more amps than your ESC can supply, but It is always a good idea to buy ESCs with a higher "max amps" than your motors draws. I would choose 25 amp max ESCs or higher.

2) In order to control the motors via PWM, I use the Servo library because you get a resolution from 700-2000 as opposed to "analogWrite" which gives a default resolution of 0-255.

3) your ESC probably has a minimum pulse width value before it will start. I would recommend writing a program that gives you the ability to plug in values from 700-2000, and use the program to slowlly find that arming pulse width value. Mine is 1110 for reference.

If you have anymore questions, I will glady answer them.

May I ask, what is your project?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I too am working on a quad. I essentially started this project to learn as much as I can about electronics, since I have just gotten into the hobby.

Comment: Nice, I have been learning a lot about quads and electronics. Message me with a question when you have one. I had a successful test flight 2 weeks ago so I can help you up to that point. I'm now on altitude hold.

Comment: @Trexter you are awesome. So glad to see a community member be so helpful, it's what makes these SE sites great. I didn't see any blog information on your profile. Do you have any examples of your autonomous arduino work you can show off?